# Xcode undefined symbols for architecture armv7s what does this mean?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I got handed an xcode project for ipad and got this error when trying to run my program:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CkoFtp2", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in LHFileBrowserDataSource.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem that appears when you need to add some Framework to you project.

Other things you can try are:

1. Ensure that the Library Search Path in Build Settings only included the appropriate folder.
2. Ensure that the correct file was referenced in Build Phases | Link Binary With Libraries section.

Reggards!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `LFFileBrowserDataSource` is linked against a library that isn't there. Look in the header file and make sure all libraries are in the project. This can happen if someone just zips up a project and sends it or doesn't copy third party libraries into the project folder when they send it.

Comment: what would i be looking for in my header file?